# How to left align the column values while building a csv using xlsx

Tags: node.js, express, xlsx

Nodejs 16.14.0
npm package: xlsx

How to left align the column values While creating CSV using xlsx in nodejs

[image: example csv]

const style = {
alignment: {
horizontal: 'left'
}
};

const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']);
for (let R = range.s.r + 1; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {
const cellAddress = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: R, c: 2 }); // Column 'C' (index 2)
const cell = ws[cellAddress];
if (cell && cell.t) {
cell.s = style;
}
}